# kettle / auto-referencing table

Tags: oracle, pentaho, kettle

I have an excel sheet with poeple, each people has a father and a mother that is in the same poeple sheet. My exel table looks like that :

**poeple**  ---    **father**  ---   **mother**

john   --------    tony    -----   jane

tony  --------     jack

I would like to import the datas to an Oracle database table that look like :

**id** --- **poeple**  ---    **father**  ---   **mother**

0 -----jack

1  -----tony-------- 0

2 -----jane

what should be my workflow ?

3 ----john -------- 1-----------2

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to at least start by loading the data into a table with the surrogate ID:

```
people father mother
------ ------ ------
john   tony   jane
tony   jack
```

Then you can add rows for the fathers and mothers not already in the "people" column:

```
insert into mytable (people)
( select mother from mytable
  union
  select father from mytable 
)
minus
select people from mytable;
```

That will give you:

```
people father mother
------ ------ ------
jack
tony   jack
jane
john   tony   jane
```

You can then add a surrogate ID for each row and use that instead, if you need it.